# Importing a space delimited string to integers

Tags: arrays, xml, string, delphi, integer

I have an XML file from which I can extract a string to a memo. The string is delimited by spaces e.g. "1 2 3 4 5 1223 2334 34 2 1" but could be tens of thousands of numbers stored as a single string.
The XML file is imported using XML data binding wiz.

I have tried the following code...

This part seems to work ok getting the string into a memo...

```
var
    Joint: IXMLJointType;
    Torques: MyArrayType;
begin
    Joint := GetJoint(XMLDocument1);
    Memo1.Lines.DelimitedText := (Joint.Torquearray[0]); //import xml string to memo
```

This part I can't seem to get to work... splitting the string into ints.

```
    for I := 1 to Memo1.Lines.Count do
    begin
      Torques[I] := (strtoint(Memo1.Lines.Text)); //import strings to array as ints
  end;
```

edit: This throws an error showing a vertical list of the string ending with "is not a valid integer" e.g.

```
'1
2
3 
4 
5 
1223 
2334 
34 
2 
1' is not a valid integer
```

These integers are sensor outputs which I want to use for graphing purposes.

Comment: You should at least state what it does when it "doesn't work". At the very least, you need to change `for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do`

Comment: Thanks Ken, my question has been amended.

Comment: Ken, you are correct about the range error. Thank you.

Comment: For better performance, use a `TStringList` instead of a `TMemo` to split the integers. If you want to display them, you can assign the `TStringList` to the `TMemo` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the range problem mentioned by Ken, you are trying to convert the whole text in the memo instead of each line. This should work:

```
for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
begin
  Torques[I+1] := (strtoint(Memo1.Lines[I])); //import strings to array as ints
end;
```

Comment: You are correct about trying to convert the whole text in the memo. Thanks for your help.